# What are differences between stand alone view and container view?

Tags: ios, uicontainerview

When I want to have a `subview` that has it's own `view controller`, I can use stand alone view that defined since XCode 7 or I can use a `container view`. But what are differences or advantages and disadvantages of these choices? (Through search I didn't find many differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main (and maybe only?) difference is that by using a `container view` you can set up the connection to the child view controller with a segue in interface builder. That means you do not have to care about the typical child view controller setup like...

```
addChildViewController(someChildViewController)
containerView.addSubview(someChildViewController.view)
someChildViewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

and so on...